# Inner wrap text element by character position

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to add a child element to another element based on a given start offset and length. Example:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit,
sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
```

With a given start offset of 6 characters and a length of 20 characters, I want to inner wrap the parent element (p) with a span element.

```
<p>Lorem <span>ipsum dolor sit amet</span>,
consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt
ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a text node, which you can split using [`splitText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Text.splitText): http://jsfiddle.net/VNY2k/.

If you have a text node `node` and split index `n`, then `node.splitText(n)` will *modify* `node` to only contain `node`'s text up to that index, and *return* a new text node with the rest of the text.

```
var node1 = ​$("p").contents()[0];  // whole text node
var node2 = node1.splitText(6);    // right of splitting point #1
var node3 = node2.splitText(20);   // right of splitting point #2
$(node2).wrap("<span>");           // node2 will contain the text
                                   // you want to wrap: right of #1
                                   // and left of #2
```

Note that you can't edit the text node itself to contain `<span>`. A text node really only contains text, and an element (e.g. `<span>`) is a node per se. As such you need to split the text nodes.

Comment: +1. I was expecting a slew of answers using jQuery's `text()` and `html()` methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked like a charm. Having a "Programmer's block" today.